# A project with a third-party library is not being built

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I have a problem when building a project in C++. Default console projects, or projects using WINAPI are going to work fine, but if I connect the SFML library, the linker gives me this: *"Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'sfml-system.lib'"*. Even before specifying the SFML libs, I added the *"opengl32.lib"* library for the test, but it is silent about it. Apparently the problem is only in third-party libraries. By the way, I'm not a newbie, I already have about a year of experience working with the SFML, but I only worked with him either in Sublim Text 3 or on another PC with the installed Visual Studio. This is the first time that I build an SFML project in my Studio on my computer since I just decided to completely switch to using the Visual Studio. I have installed Visual Studio 2017.

Screenshots:

[error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od3Wm.png)

[linker input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmcML.png)

[linker general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhZKq.png)

[c/c++ general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yroxm.png)

Comment: My only guess is you have the file path wrong or misspelled the library name .

Comment: Can not open a `.lib` in `Visual Studio` usually means one of 3 things. 1. The file does not exist where you told the IDE or you misspelled the file name or did not add the correct path in the linker's search paths, 2. The file is corrupt, or 3. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Guys, I’ve been trying to understand what's the matter for 4 hours in a row. And of course, the first thing I did was visit the Microsoft and SFML sites and tried all the possible options. But the error did not even change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not answer your question directly, but I think not many people are aware of this. You can "install" sfml for you project by **opening you project**, going **Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...** There you can browse for example for "SFML" and just install needed packages. It is much easier to work with than linking it manually, but maybe you cannot use it for some reason. As for why linking does not work in your case you'd need to show us your Linker Settings.

Comment: As for the linker settings, here are links to screenshots with them.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmcML.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhZKq.png
And about NuGet, maybe you're right! I hear about it for the first time, but it is possible that will help me. I’ll write after I try. I still need to install it, because it is not among my tools.

Comment: When I try to manually configure the linker again, the project build collapses. But! When I installed SFML through NuGet it worked! **Thank you man for such valuable advice!**